# TLS- Are there two digital signature in play during handshake

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, signature

Could you please clarify on the below doubt. 
From IBM website,
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10520_.htm

The steps of the digital signature process are as follows:

```
The sender computes a message digest and then encrypts the digest using the sender's private key, forming the digital signature.
The sender transmits the digital signature with the message.
The receiver decrypts the digital signature using the sender's public key, regenerating the sender's message digest.
The receiver computes a message digest from the message data received and verifies that the two digests are the same.
```

So there is a digital signature created using the some random message during handshake. Along with it, there is a digital signature value in the personal certificate issued by CA which is called "Digital Signature Value".  This Signature value is present in the certificate itself. But there is one more signature value created from random message during handshake also.  Why we have 2 times signature here  even for one way SSL. Where is my understanding wrong?. Thanks .

Answer (score 5):

> encrypts the digest using the sender's private key

Any time you see something about “encrypting with a private key”, expect the explanation to be flawed. There is no such thing as “encrypting with a private key”. What the writer means here is *signs the digest using the sender's private key*. Calling a signature “encryption” comes from a very limited understanding of cryptography: the two concepts have different properties and they use different algorithms. For example, it is not always possible to “decrypt” a signature and recover the digest that was signed (it's possible with some signature algorithms and impossible with others); all you can do is to *verify* whether a certain digest has a certain signature.

---

This being said, yes, there are two signatures.

1. The signature in the certificate ties the server's public key with the server's name. More precisely, it means that the certificate authority guarantees that the server with a certain name has a certain public key. This guarantees to the client that the certificate is genuine. Anybody can send you a valid certificate for *some* server name, but the certificate authority only signs a certificate if it knows that the owner of the name is also the owner of the private key associated with the public key in the certificate.
2. The signature of the digest in the handshake ties the server's public key with this particular handshake. Anybody can sign a handshake with their own private key, but not with somebody else's private key.

From the second signature, the client knows that the handshake was signed by whoever owns a certain private key. From the first signature, the client knows that the owner of a certain private key is the owner of a certain domain name. By putting the two together, the client knows that the handshake was signed by the owner of the domain name.

In fact in a typical handshake there may be more signatures. How does the client decide to trust the CA? After all anybody can sign a certificate with their own private key. In general there is a *chain* of certificates: the server's certificate is signed by a CA, the CA has its own certificate which is signed by another CA, and so on. This ends with a small set of CA certificates that are hard-coded in the client's operating system or browser. These certificates are known as *roots* of the chain. They're often called “root CAs”, but note that being a root CA is not a property of a CA, since different systems can have different sets of root CAs.

For more information about TLS, see [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work).

Comment: Thankyou for your time to explain this well. @Gilles